# Is it possible to avoid the type assertion in this generic function body?

Tags: typescript, generics, compiler-warnings, mapped-types, type-assertion

As a use case, I want to allow people to add an arbitrary function to an object, and call that function through another, using its name and parameters.

```
// Example arbitrary function
const sum = (a: number, b: number): number => a + b

// Another such function
const saySomething = (): string => Math.random() < 0.5 ? 'morning' : 'evening'

// This object holds the functions declared above
const execFn: Record<string, (...args: any[]) => any> = { sum, saySomething }

// These functions can be called through a generic function
export const exec = (name: string, ...args: any[]): any => execFn[name](...args)

console.log(exec('sum', 1, 2))
```

This works, but it's not type safe. E.g., someone can input the incorrect parameters. I can improve this using mapped types, as such:

```
type GenericFn = keyof typeof execFn

type GenericParameters = {
  [K in GenericFn]: Parameters<(typeof execFn)[K]>
}

type GenericReturn = {
  [K in GenericFn]: Parameters<(typeof execFn)[K]>
}
```

And then modifying the `exec` function signature:

```
// These functions can be called through a generic function
export const exec = <T extends GenericFn>(
  name: T,
  ...args: GenericParameters[T]
): GenericReturn[T] => (execFn[name] as (...args: any[]) => any)(...args)
```

And now, TS will properly tell if someone is calling a function without the correct parameters, and the return type is properly typed.

```
console.log(exec('sum', 1)) // Expected 3 arguments, but got 2. ts(2554)
```

**How can I remove the type assertion in the `exec` function though?**

```
// These functions can be called through a generic function
export const exec = <T extends GenericFn>(
  name: T,
  ...args: GenericParameters[T]
): GenericReturn[T] => execFn[name](...args)
```

Removing the type assertion throws the following TS error.

```
Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'GenericReturn[T]'.
  Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'GenericReturn[T]'.
    Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.
      The intersection '[a: number, b: number] & []' was reduced to 'never'
      because property 'length' has conflicting types in some constituents.ts(2322)
```

Trying to isolate the function gives me impression that the generic function is not getting exact function out of the object.

```
const fn = execFn[name]

// const fn: {
//   sum: (a: number, b: number) => number;
//   saySomething: () => string;
// }[T]
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBBCuBbGBeGAKAhgLhmJARgKYBOANDAbvosSQJTWGmoB8MA3gFAwwlFR4JMDEwwA1JS4BfLl1CRY-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)

Comment: ① The term "cast" is best avoided in TS because it is ambiguous; the conventional term is "type assertion"; could you [edit] to use that instead? ② You're quite close to the approach recommended in [ms/TS#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109) but you need to use a mapped type for `execFn` also.  As shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/NlzlrW). Does that meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz I edited my question to use the term "type assertion" instead, thank you. Also, the [playground link](https://tsplay.dev/NlzlrW) works perfectly and meet my need, that's awesome. I would not have realized I also needed a mapped type for `execFn`.

Happy to mark your answer as the resolution for my question. Thanks again!

Comment: I'll write up my answer when I get a chance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually quite close to the recommended approach for dealing with certain input-output type dependencies, as described in [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109).   In order for the following code to work:

```
export const exec = <K extends GenericFn>(
  name: K,
  ...args: GenericParameters[K]
): GenericReturn[K] => execFn[name](...args)
```

the compiler needs to see `execFn[name]` as being a single function of generic type `(...args: GenericParameters[K]) => GenericReturn[K]`.  Which means that it needs to see `execFn` is something that behaves generically when indexed by a key of type `K`.

According to microsoft/TypeScript#47109, this will happen if `execFn` is represented as a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) over the keys `K` in `GenericFn`.  Specifically:

```
const execFn: { 
  [K in GenericFn]: (...args: GenericParameters[K]) => GenericReturn[K] 
} = ⋯;
```

Since your `GenericParameters` and `GenericReturn` types are themselves written in terms of `typeof execFn`, we can't do that directly without circularity.  Let's rename your `execFn` out of the way to `_execFn`:

```
const _execFn = {
  isEven, randomInt, repeat, saySomething, sum,
} as const;

type GenericFn = keyof typeof _execFn

type GenericParameters = {
  [K in GenericFn]: Parameters<(typeof _execFn)[K]>
}

type GenericReturn = {
  [K in GenericFn]: ReturnType<(typeof _execFn)[K]>
}
```

And now we can assign `_execFn` to `execFn` of the appropriate type:

```
const execFn: {
  [K in GenericFn]: (...args: GenericParameters[K]) => GenericReturn[K]
} = _execFn;
```

And that works.

---

Note that this hinges on the *form* of the type of `execFn`.  If you look at the type of `execFn` via IntelliSense:

```
/* const execFn: {
    isEven: (n: number) => boolean;
    randomInt: (upTo: number) => number;
    repeat: (word: string, times: number) => string[];
    saySomething: () => string;
    sum: (a: number, b: number) => number;
} */
```

and compare it to the displayed type for `_execFn`:

```
/* const _execFn: {
    readonly isEven: (n: number) => boolean;
    readonly randomInt: (upTo: number) => number;
    readonly repeat: (word: string, times: number) => string[];
    readonly saySomething: () => string;
    readonly sum: (a: number, b: number) => number;
} */
```

those are basically the same (`readonly` doesn't matter here).  And of course they need to be, or else the `const execFn: ⋯ = _execFn` assignment would fail.

But the internal representation of the types are different.  The type of `execFn` is explicitly a mapped type in which each property has a generic relationship, whereas the type of `_execFn` is just a list of possibly unrelated properties.  The compiler lacks the ability to look at `_execFn` and come up with the type of `execFn` by itself; it needs to be explicitly told.

So the type of `execFn[name]` is a single function that accepts a parameter list of type `GenericParameters[K]`, which is good.  But the type of `_execFn[name]` ends up getting widened to a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of functions, which is pretty useless since unions of functions can only be safely called with an [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) of arguments (see [the TS3.3 release notes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-3.html#improved-behavior-for-calling-union-types)).   So `_execFn[name]` wants a parameter list of type `never` (i.e., there's no safe way to call this union of functions because no argument works for every call signature).

In fact the issue that eventually led to the microsoft/TypeScript#47109 approach was about these sorts of useless unions of functions, as described in [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581).  That issue is phrased in terms of "correlated unions", where you have a value `v` of a union type like `{k: "sum", fn: (a: number, b: number) => number, args: [a: number, b: number]} | {k: "saySomething", fn: () => string, args: []} | ⋯}` and you want to call `v.fn(...v.args)`, but the compiler doesn't let you.  Generic indexes are part of the solution, but you also need to have mapped types.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBBCuBbGBeGAKAhgLhmJARgKYBOANDAbvosSQJTWGmoB8MA3gFAwwlFR4JMDEwwA1JS4BfLl1CRY-AA5FMsNOgDuIEgBNc0EgEswAcwpRjiIhCa1SjOFBPmA2gF02nHjAXQ+W3gAGw0YT18AM10MYIEYY1QYAAYAbgSYAB4YKxsIdONxcXofXl5+BFCAOmV4CAALbV09el9ZcoEhEQqQqBk5IgAPZV1YfyVMMD0QRABJMDD0eGUAFRB7OicaOm9uDsFhGABZdXqqyOCQXXQTqDOSSenEdBKAKhhltZLJAEZ+riGIxIY3AAQgmAAngBlGYCeqmMxJF6GFwIti+W73R4zF4wdjJKoAVhgAH4YAByADiVz0MEQujACPJMFwVJpMCIADciIzzOSBsNRn5QbBjBAAKLckSaMAbRy4AhXOKTbwiACkMAATKgUGhknJxjAAPpDIjAABi0tKCQlUooDymM3mUHtRFU6go4OhsLuCM9SDIMlEEGFilSXAA9O9DSbBmbLbg9mV+JhpmBghCbZKebh0LK8MwGN5FSBlWBw2VAqnwBm+Ni5gtc591gWHEWUOxtqQK8m1Gnayo1FBczp9CjXBYctZbHL2+wjAjPD2OtX05mvTCbL7zLmSh3nBPl1X++ukLmcK26BQqJfHKrC+HpDBXhG5FAIaoYJSeaRjBarQA1kQEIgJEOQfkQoHGqa-5vhBX4-iYwAAAqYA8W6kCGaBJm4ADSCQiN+YC-v+Hi4Kh6ECJhmToO+qhQbG8ZgPQeEeKw-x0UQCHEUhABKnSHNhvh4QR3EkZaZEwPxBxgCsEE0ZxDEwZaLG4Wx-yGsp+Y4fhphiUhEm5lUxloWYdj6X+FGYBhJAQKxe7sERJHSV0rFBmgjH-uGkbRiKHJxv+ia+LwYrZvmeazg5lBKmo5bBXWjoNsOGDNpF95tkeg7qCOzTjn6U55Gl+4Lu4HhHhuPrwjuGBRSVZjlWeGAXl25CUEVnYPkGL4CkCIKKP5ZpJJk+FDFAPJ6CGTkGWArDoL4YDWUQuC4YGvDGVUpnmVNlloYtY22W5TjbcALnCKx3haW4C02B46DrZtrQCma6DkqFUrkhQmoACwlBGEbhCWZZeC48BEACAUvQ6TzOh9MA-MkyS-f9LVw8Z8P6jBkNukOsPkgQkwE7DADMSMHouXhuHjBMLbj+MLTTFBU-TmDkh44PPeSFVblVZjkqTdUUtSIC0vSwhMjAAA+gvslyPJMuzwAvQgiCw5qFAALSEqTKPq0TQA)

Comment: Thank you. I'm glad to see that I was close, this part was really the missing piece:

“The compiler lacks the ability to look at _execFn and come up with the type of execFn by itself; it needs to be explicitly told.”

Now I understand better what was missing. Thanks again!